# Why is "libertine" the right answer to this question?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> When staying in a hotel, Bernard would arrange for his valet to bring him his newspaper in the dining room so that everyone would realize that he had a manservant; this (i) ***_*__*_*** embarrassed his nephew who, though equally rich, preferred a more (ii)***_*__*_*_** life-style.

```
Blank (i)
A. ostentation 
B. arrogance 
C. dissimulation    

Blank (ii)
D. opulent 
E. libertine 
F. understated
```

I filled in the blanks with A. and D., but the answer given is A. and E. Why would *libertine* be an answer? *Libertine*  means an dishonest person, so how would it fit in this instance?

Comment: I think you've either misread the answer or they've got a typo.  I believe (F- *understated* should be the answer. Opulent means *ostentatiously extravagant or rich*, so D can't be right, and libertine means *having no sexual propriety* so that can't be right either.  The opposite of ostentatious is understated.

Comment: @Jim That's the answer, I think :)

Comment: @Jim Post it: it's the answer.

Answer (score 6):

I think you've either misread the answer or they've got a typo. I believe (F- understated should be the answer. Opulent means ostentatiously extravagant or rich, so D can't be right, and libertine means having no sexual propriety so that can't be right either. The opposite of ostentatious is understated